# Is there a way to lock down column positions and visibility in a grid?

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way to lock down column positions and / or visibility of columns in a grid?  This includes removing the ability to move the columns around by dragging them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `Allow` properties of `PXGridColumn` element. Judging by their names I would think that `AllowMove` and `AllowShowHide` can help achieve your goal.

Example:

```
<px:PXGridColumn DataField="BranchID" 
                 AllowMove="false" 
                 AllowShowHide="false" 
                 AllowResize="false" 
                 AllowSort="false" 
                 AllowFilter="false" />
```